# jQuery: How to parse a multidemensional array?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm not sure if the array is too deep or what, but I can't seem to get anything other than the keys and undefines. Help please!

I'm using Codeigniter for development. Here is the PHP then the jQuery:

```
 $term = $this->input->post('search_term');

  $this->db->like('book_title', $term);

  $search_query = $this->db->get('books');

  $return = array();

  $i = 0;

  if ($search_query->num_rows() > 1) {

   foreach($search_query->result() as $s) {

    $return['books']['book_id'] = $s->book_id;
    $return['books']['book_title'] = $s->book_title;
    $return['books']['book_price'] = $s->book_price;

    $i++;

   }

  } elseif ($search_query->num_rows() == 1) {

    echo 1;

    $i = 0;

    $return['book_id'] = $search_query->row('book_id');
    $return['book_title'] = $search_query->row('book_title');
    $return['book_price'] = $search_query->row('book_price');


  } elseif ($search_query->num_rows() == 0) {

    echo 0;

  }



  echo json_encode($return);
```

Javascript

```
$("#search").change(function() {

  var searchTerm = $(this).val();

  $.post("/contentcreator/search_by_term", { search_term: searchTerm }, function(data) {

     $("#book_scroller").empty();

     var lengthHolder = data.books;

     for (var i = 0; i > data.books.length; i++) {

         var row = '<li id="book_item_' + l + '">' + data.books['book_title'] +'</li>';

         $("#book_scroller").append(row);


     };

     i++;


  }, "json");

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you reformat that a bit? Nearly impossible to read. Formatting details: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help (Short version: Indent all code with four spaces.)

Comment: Separately, it would be useful to see what the actual JSON string generated by PHP and sent to the browser is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion that I have is that your returned json should be in the same format regardless of the number of books returned.  The way you have it set up if there is only one match, you return an array containing `id, title, price`, but if there is more than one you return an array containing a single(?) item books that is an array of `id, title, price`.  It seems to me that you always want it to return an array of books -- each of which is an object containing `id, title, price`.  Note that I fixed up a number of minor issues with your javascript as well.  **Disclaimer:** I'm not a php programmer by any means -- my syntax could certainly be wrong.

Try this:

```
$i = 0;

foreach($search_query->result() as $s) {

    $return[$i]['book_id'] = $s->book_id;
    $return[$i]['book_title'] = $s->book_title;
    $return[$i]['book_price'] = $s->book_price;

    $i++;

}
```

Javascript

```
$("#search").change(function() {
  var searchTerm = $(this).val();
      $.post("/contentcreator/search_by_term", { search_term: searchTerm }, function(data) {
         $("#book_scroller").empty();
         for (var i = 0; i > data.length; i++) {
            var book = data[i];
            var row = '<li id="book_item_' + book.id + '">' + book.book_title +'</li>';
                $("#book_scroller").append(row);    
         };    
      }, "json");
 });
```